# How should my copy-frameworks Run Script look with nested Carthage frameworks?

Tags: ios, frameworks, app-store, codesign, carthage

I have a Carthage framework `A` that is dependent on another of my Carthage frameworks `B`. That framework `B` is dependent on a framework `C`. My Cartfile does not have `C` listed, but as the docs describe, it is downloaded on `carthage update`. In my Run Script I have:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/A.framework
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/B.framework
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/C.framework
```

And:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/A.framework
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/B.framework
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/C.framework
```

This builds fine for me, but when I go to submit to the App Store I get `Code signing "A.framework" failed`

In the logs I see `Running /usr/bin/codesign` for

`/var/folders/1y/hdyf678f66897f_fafjdkdk89f8d/T/XcodeDistPipeline.7bM/Root/Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks/A.framework/Frameworks/B.framework/Frameworks/C.framework`

And the next line after that same string with a path to `C.framework` `replacing existing signature`, then `code object is not signed at all` on the line after that.

Do I need to specify in my Run Script the path to each sub framework (or in my case sub sub framework)?

I've tried `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/C.framework/Frameworks/B.framework/Frameworks/C.frameworks`, but then it won't compile because it can't find a file at that path (although when I cd to that path it exists).

PS:

B.framework also has a Run Script for C.framework with the same format as the main app

Comment: I also had trouble setting up something similar. I can't remember the details, but if it's any help, I have proof-of-concept projects on GitHub: https://github.com/nicolas-miari/NestedFrameworkDemo-A (replace "A" in the URL with "B" and "C" for the two other repos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bunch of issues with my project and nested frameworks. I'll list them here:

- Only the main app that will be submitted to the App Store should have a `Run Script` `copy-frameworks` Phase and it should only copy the top level frameworks.
- Only a test target should have a `Copy Files` Phase (I had a `Copy Files` phase in my framework target)
- Don't embed any frameworks (unless they are static, but those aren't officially supported as of now).
- The frameworks shouldn't be code signed themselves (It should be code signed by the main app)